# Problem about gulp-useref on duplicate content with multiple html files

Tags: gulp, duplicates, gulp-useref

When I configure useref ( gulp v3) with many html files, for example :

I first create a html page and then a second and run gulp task

**Page html01.html**

```
 <!-- build:js js/combined.min.js -->
    <script src="../../assets/script01.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/script02.js"></script>
 <!-- endbuild -->
```

**Page html02.html**

```
 <!-- build:js js/combined.min.js -->
    <script src="../../assets/script01.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/script02.js"></script>
 <!-- endbuild -->
```

Here we have the same script on many html pages

```
gulp.task('UpdateCombineCssJs', function() {
    return gulp.src('html/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

If we run the task with only html01.html and then with html02.html
combine.min.js file size, and its contents are twice.

if I add a html03.html with the same reference, size and triple content

How can I avoid duplicating content because the goal is to optimize this file : combine.min.js?
Is there a special setting?

Answer (score 0):

If you add in `gulp-changed` set to the destination directory, that should stop the file getting overwritten or added to.

```
const changed = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('UpdateCombineCssJs', function() {
    return gulp.src('html/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', cssnano()))
        .pipe(changed('dist'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```